# Non ASCII Characters in filename are skipped

Tags: php, apache, youtube-dl

The program `youtube-dl` by itself supports Non ASCII characters in filename, It works flawlessly on my webserver under root user as well as www-data user, but when I try downloading a video using youtube-dl with PHP, the Non ASCII characters are completely skipped.

Eg: `Stromae - bâtard` will be saved as `Stromae - btard.mp4` or `البث الحي` as `.mp4`

I am using this code to run the CLI command

```
function cmd($string) {
  $descriptorspec = array(
     0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
     1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
     2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
  );
  $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
  $ret = proc_close($process);
  return $stdout;
  }
$value = ('youtube-dl https://some.valid/link');
echo cmd($value);
```

Kindly advise what I should do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your phpinfo(); output for LC_ALL or LC_LANG settings.  I suspect it has nothing to do with PHP, but with the shell environment that you're using versus the shell environment your web server is using.

```
$value = ('LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 youtube-dl https://some.valid/link');
echo cmd($value);
```

Comment: OMG! I have already set the locale to en_US.UTF-8 before, It still didn't work but after trying it like you said, it just worked flawlessly :-)
Thanx a million times :D

Answer (score 1):

By default PHP use ISO-8859-1 charset. Configure PHP to use UTF-8. You can to this by adding

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

At the beggining of your script